# How to remove texture from selected faces?

Tags: texturing, uv

I have a roof. But I accidentally assigned the parts under the roof also. Now I am trying to remove texture from it. (See picture) I already tried U and then "reset" but it made my UV background white for some reason.

How does one go about it?

[image]

Comment: Probably you don't want removing the texture from roof altogether, you want to change it to another one. In that case either add one more Image texture node or assign selected faces to another material, see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/516/add-different-materials-to-different-parts-of-a-mesh

Answer (score 1):

Add one more Material and assign to the **Under the roof** part it will be a quick solution for you